# Looking for a specific type of tcp server

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I'm looking for a c# tpc server, or a tcp server that has c# interface,  that supports authentication from client to server, maybe via username/passwords or certificates, supports ssl/tls for transport and generally supports incoming channel to forward messages to server and outgoing command channel to send commands to event forwarder, like change this, and perhaps works on Mono as well as Windows, and is performant, i.e. can support multiple (dozens to hundreds of clients), as well as Windows IOCP.

I did look at WCF, but it's too vast/heavy for my requirements.

Thanks.
regards

Bob.

Comment: Node.js and learn a new language? :)

Comment: Why would WCF be "to heavy" ?  You onlu use what you need. And you need quite a few features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following which can be called from c#. Its a high performance Windows IOCP based TCP Server.

http://code.google.com/p/potatofoundation/

Comment: Found a bundle of good tcp server frameworks. The Ace framework is probably the most performant. Sits like a black hole in the computing firmament.

Answer (score 1):

IIS seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: But only practical if it hosts WCF.

Comment: I found a really nice multithreaded network server that supports IOCP written by google in c++.